# How to select none of the records belonging to an account if any of them was created after a certain date

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query where I'm selecting some basic info about the tasks of an account. There's a table ns_accounts which contains the basic info of a user's account and there's also ns_tasks which contains all the records of tasks that belong to the account. My goal is to select all the tasks with some certain conditions that I have written in my where clause, but they have to be before a certain date, in this case : 2023-04-11. However, If an account has 5 tasks, for instance, and even if one of them was created after that date, I don't want to select the rest of them, even if they were created before that date, so basically, if an account has tasks created after the date, I don't want to select that or the ones created before. Right now, the way my query works is that I can filter the tasks that were created before the date, but If an account has 5 tasks and one of them was created after the date, my query still selects the other ones, which is the opposite of what I want.
Here's my query :

```
SELECT
        max(a.id) as id,
        max(a.payID) as payID,
        max(u.name) as სახელი,
        max(ut.name) as "ანგარიშის ტიპი",
        max(u.mobile) as მობილური,
        max(u.personNo) as "პირადი ნომერი",
        max(r.name) as რეგიონი,
        max(d.name) as რაიონი,
        max(da.name) as დასახლება,
        max(ta.name) as "ტარიფის სახელი",
        max(ta.price) as "ტარიფის ფასი",
        max(ta.down) as "სიჩქარე DOWN",
        max(ta.upload) as "სიჩქარე UP",
        max(acs.name) as "ანგარიშის სტატუსი",
        max(if(a.technologyID = 0,'რადიო','ოპტიკა')) as "ანგარიშის ტექნოლოგია",
        max(a.disDate) as "გათიშვის თარიღი",
        max(if(a.deviceOwner = 0, 'არ არის საკუთრებაში', 'საკუთრებაშია')) as მოწყობილობა,
        max(ar.date) as "რეგისტრაციის თარიღი",
        max(t.id) as "დავალების აიდი",
        max(t.date) as "გაფორმების თარიღი",
        count(t.id) as "დემონტაჟების რაოდენობა"

        FROM ns_accounts a
        inner join ns_tasks t on a.id = t.aID
        inner join ns_accounts_status acs on acs.id = a.statusID
        inner join ns_tasks_resolutions tr on t.resolutionID = tr.id
        inner join ns_tasks_types tt on tr.typeID = tt.id
        inner join ns_users u on u.id = a.uID
        inner join ns_users_type ut on u.typeID = ut.id
        inner join ns_districts_area da on t.areaID = da.id
        inner join ns_districts d on da.districtID = d.id
        left join ns_regions r on d.regionID = r.id
        inner join ns_tariffs ta on a.tariffID = ta.id
        inner join ns_accounts_reg ar on a.id = ar.aID
        where a.id = 12354626 and
        a.statusID = 4 and
        ut.id = 1 and
        tt.id = 2 and
        t.status != 0
        and t.date < '2023-04-11'
        group by a.id
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add an inner query to the where clause to remove all accounts which have tasks after this date

```sql
AND a.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT aID FROM ns_tasks WHERE date >= '2023-04-11')
```